# Where did Latin come from?

Tags: historical-linguistics, latin

My understanding (supported by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Rome#Language)) is that Latin was the spoken and written language in Ancient Rome.

Therefore, I was puzzled to read the following piece of Talmud ([Gitin 80a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=80&format=pdf)):

> מאי מלכות שאינה הוגנת? מלכות הרומיים. ואמאי קרי לה מלכות שאינה הוגנת?
>   **משום דאין להם לא כתב ולא לשון**
>
> What is an "improper sovereignty"? That is the Romans. And why were
>   they called "improper"? **Because they don't have a written or spoken
>   language.**

[Rashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) there (sv שאין להם) writes:

> שאין להם לא כתב ולא לשון. אלא משל אומה אחרת
>
> "They don't have a written or spoken language" -- [this means that] they used that of
>   another nation.

The context there is a discussion of the Mishna ([Gitin 79a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=79&format=pdf)-80a) that rules that a bill of divorce (גט) that is dated by any dating system other than that of the current rulership is invalid.

Is the above information from the Talmud, together with Rashi's explanation, accurate? **If the Romans didn't create Latin, where did it come from?**

( *all above translations are mine* )

Comment: Just guessing, but it might refer to the fact that at the time the Talmud was composed administration in the Eastern parts of the Roman Empire was conducted mostly in Greek.

Comment: @StoneyB I didn't know that; that's an interesting thought.

Comment: In any case Latin descended from a common source of other Italic languages, the others of which are all extinct and Hebrew descended from a common source of other Semitic languages. The writing systems of both, and also of Greek, are all descended from the Phoenician alphabet.

Comment: @StoneyB. Rashi lived in Northern France in the 11th century. Surely he knew about Latin.

Comment: @fdb I'm pretty sure Rashi was commenting on the passage from the Talmud; and of course in Rashi's day what was left of the Roman Empire was officially Greek-speaking and had been since the reign of Justinian.

Comment: Yes, but people in France knew who the Romans were, and knew that they spoke and wrote in Latin. The Latin classics were read everywhere in Western Europe.

Comment: While the question text would have be changed considerably (to ask what the Talmud and Rashi were meaning), I think you would be much more likely to get a useful and interesting answer if this was migrated to [Judaism.SE].

Comment: @curiousdannii Why there? If we need help with translation we can ask for it.

Comment: @Alenanno Because the full significance of such a statement isn't likely to be found solely in the quotes in this question. The greater context might help.

Comment: @curiousdannii Interestingly enough, people over at MY [think that it would get a better answer here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18873792#18873792).

Comment: As @StoneyB says: as far as most people in the Eastern Roman Empire were concerned, what "the Romans" spoke was Greek. I'm sure I have read accounts whereby a word obviously meaning "Roman" in one of the languages of the area actually meant "Greek", but I'm struggling to remember where.

Comment: @StoneyB The Tosafist Rabbi [Isaac ben Samuel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Samuel) (1115-1184) understood the Talmud as referring to "an aristocratic language, a form of Greek used by the Roman kings" (*Avoda Zara* 10a, s.v. שאין).

Comment: Well, not the Roman kings, for sure, but the late Republic and especially the pre-Constantine Empire did have an aristocracy of sorts, and they did learn and speak Greek because Greek tutors.  Greek was the language of a much-admired culture, like Chinese in Asia. So it had an effect on Latin, and post-Constantine Empire was pretty much exclusively Greek in language, though they always called themselves "Romans" and the Empire "Rome". Of course Greek wasn't studied in Europe until long after Rashi. Though he probly knew it.

Comment: Maybe they meant that both the language and the alphabet originated from Greek (as it was believed in Antiquity)?

Comment: @StoneyB At the time the Misnah was composed (c. 200 AD), the administrative language was certainly universally Latin, but even at the time the Gemara was composed (c. 500 AD), it was predominantly Latin too. This didn't really change until after Justinian I, and didn't fully disappear until Heraclius' time, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is assuming Latin as a given size. Probably the answer is more like development over time.

Let me break down your question into two parts:

1. Spoken language. Roughly speaking it goes like this. The language comes from where the people is coming from. And at one point their dialect has evolved so much that their dialect no longer is mutually intelligible from the other dialects. Spoken language is normally evolved over a long period of time, rather then created at a specific point in time. Latin is believed to have been evolved from the Italic branch of Indo-European.
2. Written language. The Latin alphabet is derived from the Greek alphabet. It is believed that the earliest Latin inscription known today is a brooch from the 7th century BC. You could read more about this [here](http://www.scriptsource.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=script_detail&key=Latn).

Comment: There are some examples of languages created by individuals, like Esperanto and Elvish. They have of course been created at a certain point in time, and not developed from a dialect.

Comment: I'm thinking about this answer....the piece of Talmud that I'm looking at is [from c. 180-220 CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah), or even possibly a little earlier. From your link, it sounds like Latin was in development from 800 BCE through 500 CE, so the times are approximately correct.

Comment: Do you have any years for the development of spoken Latin?

Comment: This Wikipedia page will probably guide you in understanding the development of spoken Latin: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgar_Latin

Comment: @Shokhet: The quotation about the Romans not having "writing or tongue" (to translate literally) is not Mishna, but Babylonian Talmud. Your link to the wikipedia article on Mishna is not relevant.

Comment: @fdb That's true that the quote is from BT, but I think it's still relevant, because it's explaining the meaning of a Mishna.

Comment: No, because the passage in the Mishna does not mention the Romans.

Comment: @fdb That's true....though it would depend if you believe the Talmud's explanations of the Mishnayos are their own, or are really the intent of the authors of the Mishna (Tannaim), which was passed down orally.

Comment: @fdb Tip for you: if you want someone other than the author of the post you're commenting on to be notified of a response to a comment, you should write their username, preceded by the `@` symbol. I was not notified for your last comment.

Answer (score 7):

The Romans did have a spoken language and a written language. They even had a very rich literature. Everybody knows this. The authors of the Talmud Bavli, living in Sasanian Iraq, probably did not know anything about Latin. The statement in Gitin 80a is simply wrong. Is that a problem?

Comment: I don't doubt that the Romans spoke to each other and wrote literature. I just wasn't sure if Latin can be considered to be a "Roman language," in the sense that the Romans created it, rather than some other nation.

Comment: @Shokhet. Nobody "created" any real language. All languages evolve from some earlier language.

Comment: I understood that....was just wondering about the origins of the language.

Comment: Yes, I tend to agree... the writer of this excerpt was just ignorant of Latin, its uses, and origin, it would seem. It was very much the autochthonous language of the Romans.

Answer (score 3):

I think the mistake here is to interpret the Talmud as making a statement about Latin from the perspective of historical linguistics.

I imagine that this is simply a case of establishing legitimacy both over the region (by then completely under Roman control) and the cultural heritage.

In many contexts, language can stand for people or a particular set of religious dicta. E.g. language stands in for 'word of God' or 'commandments'.

The commentary could be quite divergent from the original intent or it could be continuing with the theme of delegitimization. E.g. saying, we are the bearers of the original language with a long line of descent going directly to creation whereas the Latins speak a mongrel language composed of many influences and even had to borrow other people's writing systems.

I'm sure there's some scholarship on this in Talmud studies.

Comment: I started looking around the commentaries.....this isn't talked about all that much, from what I've seen thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's referring to the fact that the Latin alphabet, as well as a variety of words in Latin (though not the language as a whole), come from the Etruscans?